# Implement Gaussian high-pass filter by opencv with FFT

Tags: opencv, filter, fft

I want to Implement the image enhancement according following paper like Figure 5.
http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/11/12/11357/htm

I use opencv 2.4.9 to implement FFT as following  example code:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

my question is how could I get the real and complex by the magnitude filtered by the Gaussian high-pass filter

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I shouldn't use the filter at magnitude domain. I have to use it directly on Re and Im domain.

Note: If it's must be done at magnitude domain, you need to record it's phase for getting real and complex back.